# How to get rid of this window

Tags: dual-boot, multiple-monitors, display, 20.04

An extremely annoying prompt randomly appears when im using specific apps. It happens the most when i run Neofetch. Here is a screenshot:

[image]
My question is: how can I disable it and why does it happen in the first place.

Info that may be useful (Or you can just read the neofetch in the screenshot): OS: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS x86_64
Kernel: 5.4.0-31-generic
Host: HP EliteBook 840 G1
GPU: Intel Haswell-ULT
GPU 2: AMD Radeon HD 8730M
I am dualbooting with Windows too.

**Update**: I installed KDE Plasma Desktop and it still happens. I think it happens when a program tries to fetch display information, but I'm just speculating.

**Update**: If I use lightdm and logout, it appears before its logs me out and the same thing happens when I log in.

**Update**: KDE crashes if I log in and out with error message: `VCE init error`

**Update**: I wiped my SSD and reinstalled Windows. I am having too many problems with Ubuntu. I might go with an Arch based system.

**Update**: I removed Windows and Ubuntu, then installed Arch. The problem still occurred. I answered it below.

Comment: Your problem is very weird . To get started , can you post the output of following command ? (e.g via [pastebin](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/) )  :  "strace neofetch 1>/dev/null " ( warning : there will be a huge number of lines in the output of strace.)

Comment: Here is a link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TJXqGsU2VpzSHN_tMJYnlDWP74anyk0r/view?usp=sharing If you are a windows user, rename it to .txt (for some reason its not .txt on drive)

Comment: Check all the cables and ports for your displays.  This can come up when a new display is detected.  I would not be surprised if you have a loose, damaged, or faulty cable or port.

Comment: It is not a faulty cable or port. If I remove the cable and replug it, the window does not show up. It only shows up when I run neofetch or Dos Box for example. And, it does not happen on Windows 10.

Comment: Try using a normal prompt in `~/.bashrc` and see if it still happens. Also try `screenfetch` instead of `neofetch` to rule that out.

Comment: I guess Ubuntu does not get along well with my video card for some reason. This my 4th problem related to displays.

Comment: I tried ~/.bashrc and I got:
zsh: permission denied: /home/user/.bashrc

Comment: Update: I was'nt thinking. I did `exec bash`  and the problem still occurs.

Comment: if you managed to fix it feel free to answer your own question

Comment: Okay! Thanks a lot, everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem still occured on Arch, turns out the Radeon driver was the issue. I switched to AMDGPU and everything works fine